# mocha-casperjs headless testing of a multi-client node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, phantomjs, sails.js

I have a node.js application that runs on the Sails.js MVC Framework. The application supports connections from multiple clients using socket.io in real-time. It supports different roles. For example, you can login as a standard user or as a moderator.

For testing, I use mocha-casperjs (and chai and other stuff that is not important for my question) and run the tests from grunt using `grunt mocha_phantomjs`. The tests are specified in the Gruntfile.js file in the root folder of my project. They are specified like this:

Gruntfile.js:

```
mocha_casperjs: {
  files: {
    src: [
      'test/single-client.js',
      'test/multi-client.js',
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a test case I want to verify: Once the Moderator clicks on a specific button, a `div.container` should appear on both the Moderator's view as well as the standard user's view.

Now, testing the single-client aspect works well. Here is a basic scenario:

test/single-client.js:

```
describe('Clicking on a Button as a Moderator', function() {
  it('results in div.container to appear on the Moderators view', function() {
    casper
      .start('http://localhost:1337')
      .logInAsMod() //Note: This is pseudocode for submitting a login form
      .thenClick('button')
      .then(function() {
        ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
      })
  })
}
```

which results in:

```
Clicking on a Button as a Moderator
  ✓ results in div.container to appear on the Moderator's view
```

However, I'm struggling in testing the multi-client aspect of this test case: The `div.container` should not only appear on the Moderator's view, but also on the standard user's view. From what I understand, the `casper.run()` method, which starts the tests defined earlier in the source code, will be called by the mocha-phantomjs module. So something like this won't work:

test/multi-client.js:

```
describe('Clicking on a Button as a Moderator', function() {
  it('results in div.container to appear on the Moderators view and on the standard users view', function() {
    casper
      .start('http://localhost:1337')
      .logInAsMod() //Note: This is pseudocode for submitting a login form
      .thenClick('button')
      .then(function() {
        ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
      })
    casper
      .logInAsUser() //Note: This is pseudocode for submitting a login form
      .then(function() {
        ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
      })
  })
}
```

The problem with the code above is that the `casper.run()` call only creates one instance of casperjs. It would be really great if I could write something like this:

```
var casperMod = require('casper').create();
var casperUser = require('casper').create();

casperMod
  .start('http://localhost:1337')
  .logInAsMod() //Note: This is pseudocode for submitting a login form

casperUser
  .start('http://localhost:1337')
  .logInAsUser() //Note: This is pseudocode for submitting a login form

casperMod
  .thenClick('button')
  .then(function() {
    ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
  })

casperUser
  .then(function() {
    ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
  })
```

So I would have two instances of casperjs that I can write the routines for. However, this results in `Error: Cannot find module 'casper'` because the mocha-casperjs framework does not support the inclusion of another casperjs instance.

Permanently logging out and in again is not an option, because I want to test the real-time aspect of the application.

Does anyone have a suggestion in how to achieve multiple instances of casperjs when using mocha-casperjs?

Comment: This is strange, because it doesn't look like mocha-casperjs internally uses the casperjs test command/environment where only one instance is permitted.

Comment: Could you specifiy what you mean?

Because in my test routines I don't call casper.run() myself, I assume that the mocha-casperjs module does so, which makes it hard to "inject" a second instance of casper of which run() will be called.

Comment: I scoured the source code for mocha-casperjs a bit and didn't find any evidence that `casperjs test` is used. So you should be able to use a second casperjs instance. The first one would be injected by mocha-casperjs and the second one created by you. The `casper.test` object will probably be different between the two instances. You will then probably need to get the (assert-) information that you need from the second instance by manually checking contitions without using the `casper.test` from the 2. instance. You can then call `test.pass` or `test.fail` on the 1. instance.

Comment: I don't have either grunt nor mocha-casperjs setup, so I can't verify. Because I don't know for sure, I won't write up an answer.

Comment: Thank you for now, I will try these things out and reply here once I find a reasonable way.

Answer (score 2):

You will have problems with this in any framework as you need two sets of cookies, basically two browsers running. Even if you did create two casper instances, you're still in one phantomjs process that shares the cookies.

What can do is create a new WebPage instance and swap that out on the current casper instance, plus swap the cookies:

```
casper
  .start('http://localhost:1337')
  .logInAsMod()
  .thenClick('button')
  .then(function() {
    ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
  })
  .then(function() {
    var userPage = require('webpage').create(),
    modCookies = phantom.cookies

    phantom.clearCookies()

    casper
      .logInAsUser()
      .then(function() {
        ('div.container').should.be.inDOM.and.visible;
      })
  })
```